# How to add users to case team using Apex?

Tags: apex

I have referred the following resources.

- [SOAP API Developer Guide: CaseTeamRole](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_caseteamrole.htm)
- [SOAP API Developer Guide: CaseTeamTemplate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_caseteamtemplate.htm)
- [SOAP API Developer Guide: CaseTeamTemplateMember](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_caseteamtemplate.htm)

But I am not able to find how can we assign users to case teams dynamically.
I am not able to find any link between the two. Please suggest.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamically? what's your requirement and what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
public static void shareCase(Case theCase, User caseTeamMember, String teamRole)
{
     /* get the Id for the case team role */

     CaseTeamRole role = [select Id from CaseTeamRole where Name = :teamRole limit 1];

     /* include the user on the case team */

     insert new CaseTeamMember(ParentId = theCase.Id, MemberId = caseTeamMember.Id, TeamRoleId = role.Id);
}
```

Comment: JannieT it's highly preferable to not just link to answers elsewhere. Could you include the core content of the answer given there ?

Comment: This isn't really bulk safe at all. Also in my experience inserting a `TeamMember` record without first ensuring a `Share` record is present will result in `DmlException`.